# will any usb extension cord work with usb3?

Tags: usb, cable, usb-3, cabling

I know that with 1gbit ethernet 100mbit ethernet cables won't work. You have to use cables designed for 1gbit.

What about with USB3? If I have a ten year old USB extension cable (ie. one that was made well before USB3 was) will it work at USB3 speeds? Or do I need to buy a new extension cable made specifically for USB3?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing and I've tested at work... doesn't work. I plug a USB3 disk into a USB3 port with an extension cable and Windows reports "this device can work faster...". Plugged directly into the peport works at full speed. From a quick search, USB3 extension cables are thicker...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

USB3 ports have an extra set of contacts for the USB3 connectors, but retain the standard USB2 connectors so that the ports can handle both. So your old cable will work, but only at USB2 speeds, because it has no USB3 connectors.

Comment: Can you explain why my USB3 devices don't work on a USB3 port with USB2 extension cable? I systematically went through all possible combinations, and it's only this exact combination that doesn't work